# a new window for a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if you could help me out with the following situation
I wanted to open a window thing may div in the center of the screen with blurry background i'll post a snapshot of this below

[image: A New Window Screen Shot]

please don't advise me this answer `<a href="#" target="_blank" >some text</a>`

This window should not disappear until cancel button is clicked because some time user clicks on bank side of the screen and window disappears automatically.

I dont have any code I dont even know what should i do if you cant help atleast how should i achieve this i dont needed the code i needed to know how its done...

ppl are asking research i've dont cant find any solution thats why here

Any Idea?

Comment: Try going to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396790/html-css-pop-up-window-and-disabled-background I think this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                                $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```